# Can a question be too broad even if it asks a specific not broad question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Can a question be too broad even if it asks a specific not broad question?

e.g.

[If Christian ethics are poison to Nietzsche's higher types -- what about conventional aesthetics?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/41884/if-christian-ethics-are-poison-to-nietzsches-higher-types-what-about-convent)

seems not to be asking anything broad at all, just be motivated by a broad concern, that is literature wide (the link between aesthetics and ethics).

Comment: Are you asking about that specific question or in general? It might be better to just ask why your question was closed, because in general it is too broad...

Comment: @EliranH how it is too broad, i don't understand? is the question in the title and 1st sentence too broad, or have i confused the reader into thinking i'm asking more by rephrasing it into something more general? it was meant to prompt the reader, not ask anything new!

Comment: Seems one particular moderator has an axe to grind with you. Simply [notify the parent site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) and they can see if there is a pattern of abuse. Likely, tho, it will be as effective as asking the chief of police to investigate allegations made about their son. Good luck!